# Plyer Example Applications break down on a real device

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I tried to deploy some of plyer examples on a real device (android 6) using buildozer. At first I tried camera example, but app breaks down when I tried take a picture with following error:

```
DEBUG : Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: static jfieldID 0xb052a4b0 not valid for class java.lang.Class<org.renpy.android.PythonActivity>'
DEBUG : r0 00000000 r1 00000c03 r2 00000006 r3 a0fa9978 DEBUG : r4 a0fa9980 r5 a0fa9930 r6 0000000b r7 0000010c
DEBUG : r8 b4b3f378 r9 b4d2a800 sl 00000001 fp 00000001 DEBUG : ip 00000006 sp a0fa3200 lr b6d16c41 pc b6d19030 cpsr 40070010 DEBUG : DEBUG : backtrace: 
DEBUG : #00 pc 00042030 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12) 
DEBUG : #01 pc 0003fc3d /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32) DEBUG : #02 pc 0001c3db /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10) 
DEBUG : #03 pc 0001958d /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34) DEBUG : #04 pc 000174e0 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4) DEBUG : #05 pc 00333a39 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+228) 
DEBUG : #06 pc 000f464b /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2226) 
DEBUG : #07 pc 0025aa9f /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1550) 
DEBUG : #08 pc 0025ae4d /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+64) 
DEBUG : #09 pc 000fd221 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+32) 05-30 22:32:28.979 346 346 F 
DEBUG : #10 pc 00114b01 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck16CheckFieldAccessERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEP8_jobjectP9_jfieldIDbNS_9Primitive4TypeE+452) 05-30 22:32:28.979 346 346 F 
DEBUG : #11 pc 00116525 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI8GetFieldEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP9_jfieldIDbNS_9Primitive4TypeE+524) 05-30 22:32:28.979 346 346 F DEBUG : #12 pc 00116abf /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI20GetStaticObjectFieldEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP9_jfieldID+30) 05-30 22:32:28.979 346 346 F DEBUG : #13 pc 00027357 /data/data/test.com.cameraexample/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so
```

It hapends with all plyer examples.
I use:
kivy==1.10.0
plyer==1.3.0

Can someone help me with it? I would be very grateful, Thanks!

Comment: Did you include plyer and camera permission in buildozer.spec?

Comment: I included camera permission. But how I should include plyer permission?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have plyer included in buildozer.spec file. It should look like this (near line 34):

```
# (list) Application requirements
requirements = plyer,kivy
```

and all permissions required [here](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/facades/camera.py) in (near line 54):

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

And watch out for # sign

Comment: I have set a correct permissions, but still get the same error. It seem problem is in org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the SDL toolchain?  It could be related to https://github.com/kivy/plyer/issues/245.  It looks like they may have fixed in it April (though they haven't indicated that, and I haven't checked).  Try updating plyer; it looks like they're on 1.3.1 now.

Edit:
I tried the latest version, and it didn't seem to fix the issue I'm referring to.  However, if you want a quick test to see if you're running into this problem, here's a quick hack:

```
@wrapt.patch_function_wrapper('jnius', 'autoclass')
def hack_autoclass(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
    if args[0] == 'org.renpy.android.PythonActivity':
        return wrapped('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity',
                       *args[1:], **kwargs)
    else:
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
```

This depends on the wrapt module (available on pypi) for monkey patching, but it shouldn't be too hard to monkey patch it yourself if you don't want to bother messing with the dependency (this is just the hack that I've tested personally).

Note that you'll want to call this code as early as possible.